# How to log test method name by maven command?

Tags: maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

Execution of "mvn clean install" & "mvn clean test" command executes test suit however is not logging the name test methods it executed. Please suggest how can we log the test method name for which test is executed.

Below is the sample log I am getting.

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ codebase ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/person/codebase/target/surefire-reports/unit

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Tests run: 12, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.019 sec - in TestSuite

Results :

Tests run: 12, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: Can you share your `pom.xml` file please?

Answer (score -1):

I've just found answer, please use debug options. 
mvn test --debug

For more detail, please refer below.
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/logging.html